# How to get keyword type (Organic or Paid) from Google Analytics Reporting API

Tags: web, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using Google Analytics Core Reporting API. I have a little confusion that I want to discuss.

First I want to get keyword which User has searched to reach on my site. I have used `ga:keyword`. I have also seen one other dimension which is `ga:searchKeyword`. Which one of these will give me desire result?

Second I want to get keyword type is it organic or paid? If I will use `ga:medium` then will it give me type of searched keyword?

BTY using following function to get results

```
private function getResults(&$analytics, $profileId,$data) {

    $optParams = array(

        'dimensions' => 'ga:visitCount,ga:browser,ga:fullReferrer,ga:keyword,ga:country,ga:campaign,ga:medium'
        );

    return $analytics->data_ga->get(
            'ga:' . $profileId, $data['start_date'], $data['end_date'], 'ga:visits',$optParams);
}
```

Please guide me.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ga:searchKeyword` is only for keywords from your internal site search. `ga:keyword` and `ga:medium` will give the desired result.

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets/trafficsources), `ga:keyword` tracks:

> When using manual campaign tracking, the value of the `utm_term` campaign tracking parameter. When using AdWords autotagging or if a visitor used organic search to reach your property, the keywords used by visitors to reach your property. Otherwise the value is `(not set)`.

`ga:medium` can be used to tell organic search and paid clicks apart. It tracks:

> The type of referrals to your property. When using manual campaign tracking, the value of the `utm_medium` campaign tracking parameter. When using AdWords autotagging, the value is `ppc`. If the user comes from a search engine detected by Google Analytics, the value is `organic`. If the referrer is not a search engine, the value is `referral`. If the visitor came directly to the property, and `document.referrer` is empty, the value is `(none)`.

Comment: can you please also answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041559/setting-custom-campaign-in-google-analytics-ga-js